# Images tracking using SLIC superpixels

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-segmentation, scikit-image, superpixels

l have a a set of 250 images.
From each image l apply SLIC superpixel algorithm.

Now, given superpixels of each image, l would like to track the superpixels of image **1** in image **2**.

**How to do that ?**

take 5 superpixels mask for instance in image 1, each mask with a different color. let's say we take superpixel regions 1,2,3,4 and 5 with

```
color_maks=['red', 'green', 'white','yellow', 'orange']
```

l would like to get these mask in image 1 and their corresponding mask in image 2.

My question ?

1)How to assign different color for each superpixel mask and display them in  image 1 and 2 ?

2) Given **mask 1** (with color red) corresponding to **superpixel 1** in **image 1**, how can display its mask in `image 2`. for instance :

```
regions_image_1=[ 1,2,3,4,5]

corresponding_region_in_image_2=[7,2,5,8,12]
```

For the sake of illustration :

Let's take region 1 in image 1 with `mask_color='red'`. Display it in image 1 and dispaly its correspoding in **image 2** which is **region 7** with the same `mask_color='red'`

**What l have tried ?**

```
def display_mask_superpixel(image):

    image = cv2.imread(image)
    segments = slic(img_as_float(image), n_segments=50, sigma=5)
    # show the output of SLIC
    fig = plt.figure("Superpixels")
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.imshow(mark_boundaries(img_as_float(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)), segments))
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()
    plt.cla()
    plt.close()

    for (i, segVal) in enumerate(np.unique(segments)):
        # construct a mask for the segment
        print("[x] inspecting segment %d" % (i))
        mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
        mask[segments == segVal] = 255

        # show the masked region
        cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)

        cv2.imshow("Applied", cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask))
        cv2.waitKey(0)

List_of images=images

for image in list_of_images:
    display_mask_superpixel(image)
```

The limit here is that :

1) l display all superpixels of a given image , however l would like to display just some regions

2) all the mask are in white, however l'm looking for a different color for each mask

3) Don't handle tracking superpixel region of image 1 in image 2

Hope it's clear
Thank you

Comment: What if the superpixels don't match at all? How do you define "corresponding"?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, The correspondace is done with optical flow.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, so my question here is just how to visualize in the same image superpixels with different color masks 2) their corresponding as given in 2)